# Prove that if $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow A$ are such functions, that $gf = I_A$, then $f$ is 1-1 and $g$ is onto.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that if $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow A$ are such functions, that $gf = I_A$, then $f$ is 1-1 and $g$ is onto.
Knowing that $gf = I_A \equiv gf : A\rightarrow A$, I had an idea to present $gf$ function as
$$gf(x) = x$$
Then for any element $x\in A$, function $gf$ is true.
But what should I do next in order to prove that $f$ is 1-1 and $g$ is onto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $x\in A$, $x=gf(x)$, so $g$ in onto.

For every $x,y\in A$, if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $x=gf(x)=gf(y)=y$, so $f$ is 1-1.

Answer (score 0):

It's really nothing more than following the definitions. Assume $f(x)=f(y)$. Take $g$ on both sides and you get $x=gf(x)=gf(y)=y$, so $f$ is one to one. Now let $x\in A$. Then $g(f(x))=gf(x)=x$. That shows $g$ is onto.

Answer (score 0):

For any $a\in A$ we have $f(a)\in B, g(f(a))=a$ hence $g$ is onto. Then for any $a,a'\in A$ such that $f(a)=f(a')\implies a=g(f(a))=g(f(a'))=a'$ so $f$ is 1-1.